# How to fetch JSON response to PHP variable?

Tags: php, json, getjson

I am sending a json response from a php file like

```
$start = 2;
$startJson = array('start' => $start);
echo json_encode($startJson);
```

And receiving a JSON response in another php file like {"start":"2"}  [image]

Now how to fetch this data "2" to a PHP variable. i tried..

```
$json = file_get_contents('sortCategory.php');
$data = json_decode($json);
echo data;
```

After that i got this error:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant data - assumed 'data' in F:path to .php on line 322
```

please provide any solution to fetch JSON response to PHP variable?

Comment: missed `$`. should use `print_r($data)` to check array value.

Comment: Empty array getting printed, but i am reciving the JSON request {"start":"2"}

Comment: @user466061! check variable `$json` first. what you getting. Use `echo $json`.

Comment: @Anant
$start = 2;
$startJson = array('start' => $start);
echo json_encode($startJson);

Comment: @Yash it is printing everything in sortCategory.php file

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. The code is `echo data;`. `data`, because is not prefixed with a dollar sign (`$`) must be a constant but no such constant is defined. PHP dutifully reports this situation and considers in fact you wanted to write `echo 'data';`. Regarding JSON decoding, read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). The second argument of the function makes the developer's live easier, most of the time.

Comment: @user466061 you get solution but not interested in marking answers. its not right. I am deleting my answer because no use to help.

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents()` reads entire file into a string, so it won't execute your php script. You have to put only json value inside you sortCategory.php file (not required to put .php extension, can use .txt as well). If you want to run php script then you could use `include` or `require` function either.

You can try this with `file_get_contents()`:

**sortCategory.php**

```
{"start":2} // array in json format
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('sortCategory.php');
$data = json_decode($json);
print_r($data);
?>
```

In this case you don't need to name your file as `.php` extension. `sortCategory.json` would be better.

Comment: i have category.php and i am sending some values to sortCategory.php through ajax, and there is bunch of PHP codes in sortCategory.php, Now i have to send the start=2 to category.php again. is there any way to do that with JSON or without JSON?

Comment: For this you have to use `AJAX` function.